# Scanl in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

```
scanl (\exp y -> scanl (\x -> if (isLetter x) then update exp (Literal x) "" else 
                    if x=='+' then update exp Epsilon "+" else
                    if x=='*' then update exp Epsilon "*" else
                    update exp Epsilon "|") y) Epsilon q
```

I have a list of [Char] and I want to transform them into my data type but I am having some problems with it.
I have somenthing like this ["a+b","c*d"] and I want the result of when I apply scanl on "a+b"
to remain so I can use it for the second list. Can someone help me ?

My data type is:

```
data Reg = Epsilon | Literal Char | Or Reg Reg |  Then Reg Reg |  Star Reg  deriving Eq
```

and

```
update:: Reg -> Reg -> [Char] -> Reg 
update a b "" = (a `Then` b)
update a b "|"= (a `Or` b) 
update a b "*" = (Star a) 
update a b "+" = (plus a)
update a b "?" = (opt a)
```

And I am trying to transform something like this ["a|","bc"] to (Then a (Or b c))

Comment: Can you give a bit more context about the big picture? What are `Literal` and `Epsilon`? What does `update` do? What are you trying to achieve in general?

Comment: @AndrewC This would appear to be an idealized NFA. I have no clue what the `scanl` expression is supposed to be doing, but the Reg type clearly corresponds to nondeterministic regular expressions.

Comment: @Carl This is apparent from the edit Edy made following my comment, yes.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, `scanl` isn't great at passing state along, and especially here you don't want the result to be a list at all, but just a final result. The more generalized approach would be to use a `fold` instead.